# Generate alarms and notifications and send mail based on a condition in Python

Tags: python, notifications, yaml, etcd, alarms

I am running an etcd cluster in my machine. I have added three members too.
Is it possible to generate the an alarm/notification based on the condition that cluster is healthy/not-healthy and is it possible to read some email-ids from a YAML file and send a mail to these ids. I am able to do it in GO but not in Python. I just want directions to some websites or maybe some code from where I can infer and start.

The curl request is:

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:2379/health
```

And the output is:

```
{"health":"true"}
```

However there is another way through command-line:

```
./etcdctl cluster-health
```

And the output is:

```
member 8e9e05c52164694d is healthy: got healthy result from http://localhost:2379
cluster is healthy
```

I want the second result, parse it and then put my conditions like wait and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxfGXXEaDA0 on youtube where it is shown that you can send notification to slack using python. You can run the following code to execute any external command in python.

`import os
 os.system("./etcdctl cluster-health")`